# Connect Firebase Auth with Firestore in React

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to figure out how to connect users with data in my firestore. I didn't find anything about how to do it in React.

My idea, in the register page of my app, is:

```
async function register() {
    try {
        await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(data => {
        auth.currentUser.updateProfile({
            displayName: name
        })
        db.collection('usersdata').doc(data.user.uid).set({nome: name})
        props.history.replace('/success')
        })
    } catch(error) {
        alert(error.message)
    }
}
```

In this way I'm creating a new user and also a new entry in my "usersdata" collection. That entry has the same ID and the same name of the user.

After the login I can get the active user name using:

```
const userName = getCurrentUsername()
function getCurrentUsername() {
        return auth.currentUser && auth.currentUser.displayName
    }
```

All of this is working. But here it comes my problem:

I would like to add new data to the current user, for example "age" and "nationality".

But I don't know how to exactly get access to that user from firestore instead of auth.

And I also need to return only his data. Then, after a research, I need to return data from all users, and I guess that is the method:

```
const [datidb, setDatidb] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
        const data = await db.collection('usersdata').get()
        setDatidb(data.docs.map(doc => doc.data()))

        }  
        fetchData()

    },  [])
```

Comment: I guess I got it. I can do something like this:
'''
function handleTest() {
      db.collection('usersdata').doc(auth.currentUser.uid).get().then(doc => {
         console.log(doc.data().nome)
       })
    }
'''

and in this way I'm getting data from firestore starting by the user logged in. 

now I would like to create a const "activeUser" in order to get the data in my component calling it by {activeUser.name} or {activeUser.age} ... any suggestions?

Comment: You may find support for Firebase here: https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact